# How to fix suffixIcon css for multiple mode in antd Select

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using antd Select component, antd version 3.24.0, I have a requirement to show clear all text on the right side, The css for this suffixIcon is messed when i use mode="multiple". The suffixIcon is overlapping with tags. How do we fix this? Attaching a sandbox link below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-fog-frh2gt?file=/index.js

I expect the tags to not overlap with the icon, and everything to be displayed in a single line, hence using maxTagCount and maxTagLength.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi, can you push using css margin for your "clear-icon" or text? ``` .ant-select-selection__rendered {
  margin-right: 60px !important;
}``` in order to avoid overlap on icon.  [foke your example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cherry-knvwrc?file=/index.js)